# Time Off Request and Setting date to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: google-apps-script

To start with I am a total novice at GAS. Im trying to a digital time-off request using google forms and google sheets that sends out an email when approved.

I have it working but I am running into an issue because I want to print the time in a format without the extra time at the end.

I was able to get it to work by adding .toLocaleDateString("en-US") to the variables but I realized it wont work if the the cell is blank.

I would like that to run on the cell that is filled. Either column f&k when a full day is taken or column I if late.

A nice extra would be after the email is sent the row is moved to the "approved" tab.

A copy of the google sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HdFERMvFtgcmqoPOe4yvD7i-HyFgo132wCnTaY-IGwA/edit?usp=sharing

```
function sendEmailedit(e){
if (e.range.columnStart != 12 || e.value != "TRUE") return;    
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
let y = rData\[0\]\[10\];
let late = rData\[0\]\[8\]
let beg = rData\[0\]\[5\];
let end = rData\[0\]\[6\];
let ESLP = "https://docs.google.c"
let Subject = "Staff absence/time off request for";
let cc = "pn, td, ma"
let msg = "Your staff absence/late request for" + " " + beg + "-" + end + " " + late + " " +           "has been approved by ." + "<p>" +
 "<b>\<u\>All Staff:</b>\</u\>" + "<br>" +
 "Please add a banner reminder (all day) onto Google Calendar and include both es and es" + "       <p>" +
"<b>\<u\>Teachers:</b>\</u\>" + "<br>" +
"Please email your lesson plans to ma and pn by 8:00am the day you will be out" + "<p>" +
"<b>\<u\>Sub plans must include:</b>\</u\>" + "<br>" +
"classroom procedures, clear directions for the scholars/ substitute, and an agenda with time         stamps. You can use your own template or the" + " " + '\<a href="' + ESLP + '"\>ESAT Sub Lesson     Plan</a>' + "<p>" +
"Thank you!";

Logger.log(msg);

GmailApp.sendEmail( y , "Staff absence/late request", msg,{
htmlBody: msg});
}

Thank you for any help!
```

I would like that to run on the cell that is filled. Either column f&k when a full day is taken or column I if late.

A nice extra would be after the email is sent the row is moved to the "approved" tab.

Comment: Look at [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Comment: Or just use setNumberFormat() and getDisplayValues()

Comment: Thanks I will try to work with these. I am like super fresh. This is the first thing I have even tried to buid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From:**

```
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getValues();
```

**To:**

```
const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,11).getDisplayValues();
```

Then you may also use this code to move that row to "Approved" sheet:

```
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var rowValues = rowRange.getDisplayValues()[0];
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Approved");
  targetSheet.appendRow(rowValues);
  sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
```

### Final code:

**Try:**

```
function sendEmailedit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 12 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 11).getDisplayValues();
  let y = rData[0][10];
  let late = rData[0][8]
  let beg = rData[0][5];
  let end = rData[0][6];
  let ESLP = "https://docs.google.com/document/"
  let Subject = "Staff absence/time off request for";
  let cc = "test1@email.com, test2@email.com, test3@email.com"
  let msg = "Your staff absence/late request for" + " " + beg + "-" + end + " " + late + " " + "has been approved by Ms." + "<p>" +
    "<b><u>All Staff:</b></u>" + "<br>" +
    "Please add a banner reminder (all day) onto Google Calendar and include both test4@email.com and test5@email.com" + "<p>" +
    "<b><u>Teachers:</b></u>" + "<br>" +
    "Please email your lesson plans to test@email.com and test2@email.com by 8:00am the day you will be out" + "<p>" +
    "<b><u>Sub plans must include:</b></u>" + "<br>" +
    "classroom procedures, clear directions for the scholars/ substitute, and an agenda with time stamps. You can use your own template or the" + " " + '<a href=\"' + ESLP + '">ESAT Sub Lesson Plan</a>' + "<p>" +
    "Thank you!";

  Logger.log(msg);

  GmailApp.sendEmail(y, "Staff absence/late request", msg, {
    htmlBody: msg
  });

  //Move this row
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();;
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var rowRange = sourceSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  var rowValues = rowRange.getDisplayValues()[0];
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Approved");
  targetSheet.appendRow(rowValues);
  sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Copy/Move row to another sheet](https://sheetautomation.com/blog/copy-move-row/)

Comment: That worked! Anyway you can edit your response to remove emails? I didn't realize the unedited version was accessible

Comment: @JonathanLineses done, sorry about that. Yeah it was accessible from the script of the sample spreadsheet link you've shared. Missed pointing that out. Glad your concern is resolved!